# How to fetch updateAuthority of the NFTs without using metaplex js library?

Tags: metaplex, nft, metadata, spl

How can I fetch an NFT's `updateAuthority` without using `@metaplex-foundation/js`?

Comment: @john's answer is great, but the more constraints you can add to this question the better (eg. ‘using Rust,’ or ‘from the command line’).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could also look at using metaboss to decode the specific nft mint youre looking to work with and from there recover the update auth.

have a look at metaboss here:
https://metaboss.rs/decode.html

metaboss will also allow for pretty much any NFT functionality you would like to have through the command line.

You will probably have to parse the output yourself to recover the update auth any other info u needed

Answer (score 4):

Try `getAssetsByAuthority` from DAS API through Helius

https://docs.helius.dev/compression-and-das-api/digital-asset-standard-das-api/get-assets-by-authority